# Выделение памяти malloc - недопонимание

Tags: c

Функция `filename_new` формирует имя файла с форматом `.new` в конце названия файла, которое мы передаем программе таким образом `./exe file` и эта функция формирует указатель на строку `c` с выделением памяти под длину названия файла и вот у меня назрел вопрос, почему моя программа работает, если я выделяю память под 4 байта (если я передам имя `file` программе) и затем добавляю еще символы `.new`получается ведь нужно 8 байт выделить? То есть написать

```
len = strlen(argv[1]) + 4;
```

Потому что `.new` это еще 4 байта

Но моя программа работает и без этого таким образом, почему?

```
char* filename_new(char **argv)
{
        int len;
        char *c;

        len = strlen(argv[1]); // strlen возвращает 4, ибо я передал имя file
        c = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        sprintf(c, "%s.new", argv[1]);
        return c;
}
```

В итоге получается, что функция возвращает `file.new` и это правильно, но я просто понять не могу, нужно ли выделять еще +4 байта из-за `.new` И почему компилятор не возвращает ошибку из-за того что я выделил чуть меньше чем надо, это же ведь неправильно?

Comment: 1. потому что компилятор не следит за динамической памятью. 2. по идеи нужно выделять достаточное количество памяти. скорей всего он не дописывает данные.

Comment: Работает только на везении. По соседству с выделенной оказалась память, которая тоже принадлежит текущему процессу, и записать туда не проблема. Но эта память может относиться к другой переменной, и тогда её содержимое будет испорчено, а программа, будь она сложнее, стала бы вести себя непредсказуемо

Comment: Ну и конкретно для приведенного кода, попробуйте _asprintf()_. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Язык си очень доверяет программисту. И ругается только если совсем-совсем плохо. Поэтому он не будет такое проверять - программист лучше знает. Более того, часто это просто невозможно - если строка вводится в уже процессе работы программы, то как компилятор об этом сообщит? Но он может добавить проверок, если Вы явно об этом попросите. В gcc/clang это `-fsanitize=memory`. И в процессе выполнения программы Вы узнаете все, что хотите.

Почему же это работает? Очень часто рантайм выделяет немного больше памяти, чем Вы попросили. И нет никаких проблем записать туда. А также возможно Вам просто повезло и там была свободная память, никем не занятая. Но в один день там окажется другая переменная и будет плохо.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, понял теперь